# mkdir: cannot create directory 'usb': No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I'm getting the message mkdir: cannot create directory 'usb': No such file or directory when I try to execute this command in /proc/bus. usb doesnt exist in this file (I'm trying to get around the usbfs omission). can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/proc` is a virtual filesystem; you cannot create files or directories within it, all contents are created by kernel modules.